# Restore Bak File created on Windows XP pro in Windows XP Pro 64

Tags: windows, backup, restore

I have a situation that I need help with. I backed up my Files on Windows XP using the System > BackUp utility/wizard, and then Installed a new operating system on the machine. Now I want to restore my old files via the .bkf file but it is not being recognized at all. Did I do this wrong or is there a way to still get back my old files on my new OS ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Download the Windows NT Backup Restore Utility for Windows 7 and for Windows Server 2008 R2 from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974674).  This will allow you to restore from a .BKF file.